# Path issues in webpack component. Need expertise

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js

Can anyone experienced with Webpack/npm components take a loot at: https://github.com/appcomponents/material-components/issues/4 ?

Basically - it is giving error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./components"` when using this package with npm inside webpack project.
Simple for someone with knowledge but totally blocking for someone totally not into components/webpack.

It's some simple issue with path configuration which is making it impossible to use this really nice package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about spamming a help issue on another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have copied my comment from the GitHub issue as this should have as much visibility as possible.*

The issue is with the `webpack.config.js`. It's not resolving modules correctly.

I've created a pull request ([#8](https://github.com/appcomponents/material-components/pull/8)) to resolve this issue. You can use that repo commit in the meantime, or you can modify the `webpack.config.js` file manually in `node_modules/vue-material-components/`. I've tested this with a known working Vue.js webpack config.